# How to get Array of array(result values Specially CommentUser[] and BarLike[]) from json string using jackson in Android?

Tags: android, arrays, parsing, jackson

I want to get the value of `CommentUser[]` and `BarLike[]` but not able to fetch that array of array from this JSON string .

Please refer this link for View my parsing code : 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/rws784060dblbq4/Untitled.png?dl=0

```
{
    "success": "1",
    "msg": "Closures found.",
    "details": {

    },
    "result": [{
        "name": "Miles Davis",
        "birthDate": -1376027600000,
        "CommentUser": [{
            "like": 0,
            "unlike": 1
        }],
        "BarLike": [{
            "like": 0,
            "unlike": 1
        }]
    }]
}
```

Comment: post your parsing code

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please show your code. We can't write code for you.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rws784060dblbq4/Untitled.png?dl=0

Comment: please open this link have send the image of parsing code

Comment: @jalpazala, Just copy paste your parsing code, by editing this question again , so people can help you

Comment: I have add a link were people can see my code.

Comment: The code you posted show no json parsing, there is no reference to any Jackson class.  I didn't see any reference to any other json parser.  all I could see was call some loadData() method that produces a response which you cast into BarDetailCommentResponse.  is this json parsing?